# JSON null error Android

Tags: android, json

```
         private static final String KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ ="trainingCountRead";
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    c = null;
                    c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                training.setTrainingID(c.getInt(KEY_TRAINING_ID));
                training.setTrainingEvaluation(c.getInt(KEY_TRAINING_EVALUATION));
                training.setTrainingAim(c.getString(KEY_TRAINING_AIM));
                training.setTrainingExplanation(c.getString(KEY_TRAINING_EXPLANATION));
                training.setBehaviorID(c.getInt(KEY_BEHAVIOR_ID));
                training.setTrainingTotalQuestion(c.getInt(KEY_TRAINING_TOTAL_QUESTION));
                training.setTrainingHood(c.getString(KEY_TRAINING_HOOD));
                training.setTrainingCreateTime(c.getString(KEY_TRAINING_CREATE_TIME));
                training.setTrainingOK(c.getInt(KEY_TRAINING_OK));

                if(c.getString (KEY_TRAINING_NAME_READ) != null) {
                    training.setTrainingNameRead(c.getInt(KEY_TRAINING_NAME_READ));
                }

                if(c.getString (KEY_TRAINING_SHAPE_READ) != null) {
                    training.setTrainingShapeRead (c.getInt(KEY_TRAINING_SHAPE_READ));
                }

                if(c.getString (KEY_TRAINING_COLOR_READ) != null) {
                    training.setTrainingColorRead (c.getInt(KEY_TRAINING_COLOR_READ));
                }

                if(c.getString (KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ) != null) {
                    training.setTrainingCountRead (c.getInt(KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ));
                }
```

error is

> org.json.JSONException: Value null at trainingCountRead of type
>   org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to int 06-07 12:33:15.784
>   17830-17830/com.example. W/System.err:

for

```
if(c.getString (KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ) != null) {
                    training.setTrainingCountRead (c.getInt(KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ));
                }
```

value is that

```
 training: [
    {
    trainingID: "154",
    trainingEvaluation: "81",
    trainingAim: "Şekil Eğitimi",
    trainingHood: "3 temel şekli basit geometrik şekiller ile öğretme",
    trainingExplanation: "3 temel şekli basit geometrik şekiller ile öğretme",
    behaviorID: "3",
    trainingTotalQuestion: "33",
    trainingOK: "1",
    trainingCreateTime: "1464647671",
    trainingNameRead: "0",
    trainingShapeRead: "1",
    trainingColorRead: "1",
    trainingCountRead: null
```

i check for null, why does it go inside even if it is null?

```
} }catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d(TAG, "checkdatabase hata,jsnarytrainingset");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Islem basarisiz, lutfen hocanızla iletisime geciniz...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("username", username);
intent.putExtra("wasDbExisted", true);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity) context).finish();

}
```

Comment: Try to print the c.getString (KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ) value

Comment: And your are asking for a string but expecting a int...

Comment: for Log.d(TAG,"c.getString (KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ) " log is c.getString (KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ) null

Comment: because i dont want null ints

Comment: .equals("null"); i made this and worked

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
if(c.getString (KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ) != null && !c.getString (KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ).equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                    training.setTrainingCountRead (c.getInt(KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the value of JSON key is `null`, JSONObject parses it as `"null"`(a string). If you compare it like below it will return true.

`c.getString(KEY_TRAINING_COUNT_READ).equals("null");`

Refer `JSONObject` documentation for more details : https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

You can also use `JsonReader` to parse the JSON. It reads JSON as a stream of tokens and there you can compare `null` value with an Enum `JsonToken.NULL`.

I prefer `JsonReader` whenever the JSON is large and complex. In your case, I will say use `JSONObject` (you are already using it). Just create a final String variable with `"null"` value and instead of comparing the JSON strings with `null` compare it with the final variable.